# How long does it take for diarrhea to pass through the bowels?

Tags: digestion, diarrhea, irritable-bowel-syndrome, intestine, length-of-time

I would be interested to know how much time does it take for diarrhea to pass through the human bowels? I am looking for a timeline, eg 2-3 hours vs the regular 6-8.

Comment: Can you narrow down your question by providing some context (food poisoning, a disesae..)? Also, is your question about how long does diarrhea last or haw fast a certain piece of food goes through the bowel during diarrhea?